# Editing an image without creating a new one

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, three.js

I'm trying to edit an image (`img` element) with JavaScript but google only gives me info about how to create a new image with the desired changes.
For performance reasons what I want to be able to do is to edit an existing image without creating a new one - is this at all possible via JavaScript in a browser environment?

What I'm trying to accomplish is to edit a rather large uv map of a `three.js` model on the fly without having to constantly re-create the whole image (performance concerns).

Comment: Can you render the image, save it into a target?

Comment: have tried changing the `src` attribute of the image element

Answer (score 0):

There's a cool library to work with images: [p5.js](http://p5js.org)

I'm not sure it's able to directly modify an img element created with HTML, but if it's not a problem for you to load the image using JS then this works just fine.

[Here](http://p5js.org/examples/examples/Color_Brightness.php) an example on how to modify pixels brightness:

```
var img;

function preload() {
  img = loadImage("image.png");
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(720, 200);
  img.loadPixels();
  loadPixels();
}

function draw() {
  for (var x = 0; x < img.width; x++) {
    for (var y = 0; y < img.height; y++ ) {
      // Calculate the 1D location from a 2D grid
      var loc = (x + y*img.width)*4;
      // Get the R,G,B values from image
      var r,g,b;
      r = img.pixels[loc];
      // Calculate an amount to change brightness based on proximity to the mouse
      var maxdist = 50;
      var d = dist(x, y, mouseX, mouseY);
      var adjustbrightness = 255*(maxdist-d)/maxdist;
      r += adjustbrightness;
      // Constrain RGB to make sure they are within 0-255 color range
      r = constrain(r, 0, 255);
      // Make a new color and set pixel in the window
      //color c = color(r, g, b);
      var pixloc = (y*width + x)*4;
      pixels[pixloc] = r;
      pixels[pixloc+1] = r;
      pixels[pixloc+2] = r;
      pixels[pixloc+3] = 255;
    }
  }
  updatePixels();
}
```